# Passing methods as a argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, methods, functional-programming, this

I'm writing a function which will allow me to display the values of an array by passing another function as a value.

This code works just fine:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
forEach(["foo", "bar", "qux"], alert);
```

But it throws and error if I try to pass a function with a property:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
forEach(["foo", "bar", "qux"], console.log);
```

If I do this:
`action.log(array[i]);`
it works just fine, but that would only allow me to pass functions with a `.log` property. Is there any way I can write a function which allows me to pass another function and property as a value?

Comment: related: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) - pass `console.log.bind(console)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't using a method of an object, it's a `console.log` specific problem. [Bug report here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989619). For `console.log` specifically, you can bind context to it, for example:

```
forEach(["foo", "bar", "qux"], console.log.bind(console));
```

Other methods will work fine, for example:

```
var x = {
    test: function(str){
        alert(str);
    }
}

forEach(["hello", "world"], x.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
function forEach(array, action) {
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  action(array[i]);
}
forEach(["foo", "bar", "qux"], function(x){ return console.log(x) });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, it is expected because console.info expects its "this" reference to be console, not window. Otherwise, I found it working in Firefox 32 / IE.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=48662